# How to extract specific text from JSON response

Tags: python, json, tweepy

I am using the Twitter API to source tweets, and am using their provided GitHub example. However, the tweets are given in a JSON format. How can I extract one part (specifically the text and tag) and place it into either a list, dataframe (most ideal option), dict etc?

```
    for response_line in response.iter_lines():
    if response_line:
        json_response = json.loads(response_line)
        tweets.append(json_response)
```

Upon viewing the 'tweets' list, the data uses the following format:

```
{'data': {'id': '1562362833374945281',
'text': 'Waiting ......'},
'matching_rules': [{'id': '1562362617708027906', 'tag': 'bitcoin'}]}
```

Comment: The JSON is already parsed for you, this is just basic use of lists and dictionaries.

Comment: json_response['data']['text'] should give you the id value. JSON docs show that json.loads returns a dict usually: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json.loads()` returns a dictionary. So e.g. to get the text:

```py
json_response = json.loads(response_line)
text = json_response.get("data").get("text")
```